# The Date Modified is not updated on Finder on the Mac

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

This is the first time I saw this: I have a folder on an external hard drive (not sure if that matters), and then viewing it as a "list", I can see the Date Modified showing the dates and time.

Now, however, I know some app is modifying the file, so for example, the file should show it was modified one minute ago, such as "1:17pm".  However, it doesn't update... it is still showing as "9:03am"...

It is running with Big Sur... and I used a Mac running Monterey and view that folder through the network and it is the same: 9:03am.  To double check, I ran Bash and did a `ls -lt`, and do see it modified at 1:17pm.

So to double check again, I change the view to "Icons", and then back to "Details", and now it is updated to 1:17pm.

So what is this about?  Is this a bug or feature, and is there a way I can tell Finder to more diligently update the timestamp?  I suspect it may be due to an external drive but not entirely sure if that's the cause.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329136/why-is-date-modified-for-a-folder-earlier-than-date-modified-for-files-inside-in?rq=1

Comment: But maybe you could instead ask whether there is a way to achieve your desired behaviour using finder? I certainly would be interested in that!

Answer (score 3):

I think it has something to do with how the External Hard Drive is formatted. I noticed the same issue on an external drive that was formatted to "ExFAT" which is compatible with both mac and pc. When a drive is formatted under "Mac OS Extended" it seems to work properly and folders are updated with the correct "date modified".

Comment: That is indeed correct.